# Can owning a static website without advertisements be a source of income in India?

Tags: india, income, websites

Suppose I create a static website (just contains some information to read), and assume 1000 visits daily. The website does not contain any advertisements.

Can it be a source of (even small) income?

Comment: Where do you think the income would come from?

Comment: For visiting my site! @Ben Miller

Comment: Are you suggesting that you would charge your readers money for visiting your site?

Comment: @Ben Miller I am asking for a website that is open for access...

Comment: If you have a website that is open for anyone to read and has no advertisements, how do you think it would generate income for you? Where would the money come from?

Comment: I'm in doubt whether it is possible to get money from visitors by hosting a website. But from your comments, I'm learning that it cannot be a source of income. @Ben Miller

Comment: @Ben Miller then why do the internet service providers charge money based on the data used if no money is deposited into the website owners!

Comment: @hanugm Not only that, but Internet service providers will also charge _you_ money to keep your site connected to the Internet so that people can visit it.

Comment: @hanugm They charge because bandwidth (and infrastructure) costs money. Not because they're running a charity for website makers.

Comment: **Not only in India**, I think a static website without any advertisements and no collection from visitors cannot be a source of income in the world! But yes it can be a **source of expense**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order for any activity to generate income, you need to be able to point to where the money is coming from.

Websites owners generally generate income three ways:

- They might charge users to use the site (paywall).
- They might have advertisements, in which case sponsors pay the site owner to put the advertisements on the site.
- They might sell a product to users from their website.

If you aren’t doing one of these things, your site won’t generate any income. Websites don’t create money.

The money that you pay for internet access does not go to the content creators/website owners. You are paying for internet access, not content. It is like paying for transportation to a store. You might pay a train fare to get yourself to a store, but once you are at the store you must pay again to actually receive something from the store. The store owner doesn’t get any of the money you paid on the train.

Comment: I saw the title of this question, and immediately figured it was from a new member that did not understand what is on topic. Then I saw that a high rep member already answered it and has up votes. I think we have very different ideas about what is on topic. I also have no interest in alienating The member with the second highest rep here. So I will ignore this question.

Comment: You missed "Javascript cryptocurrency miner" as option 4. /s

Comment: Excellent analogy: "The store owner doesn’t get any of the money you paid on the train."

Comment: @AaronD.Marasco I suppose that would be an example of a website actually creating money. :)

Answer (score 2):

As far I know, there are following ways to earn money from the website:

1. Allow advertisements on your blog
2. Make your services/contents paid/licensed
3. Voluntary payment/Donation
4. Collect user data (caution: legal issues ahead...)

If you want to avoid advertisements on your web site, you still have two other ways to earn money.

Second way (paid/license) does not look most suitable to you as you are asking this question here. The better way is the third one. If visitors (if any) like your contents, you may ask (request) for donation.

Comment: I'd respectfully caution you on the word 'donation', as it implies something that is not true. Namely that such money is not taxable. It is, in all jurisdictions, as far as I know.

Comment: The OP is not asking how to earn income from a website?